# Bootstrap website shown before it's fully rendered - Glyph icons not working either

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that I'm testing across browsers. In IE(8) and Chrome(Version 54.0.2840.87 m), it takes a bit of time before loading, but once it does it's rendered completely. However, in Firefox(43.0.1) it shows incompletely rendered html elements for a second before rendering properly. Also, I've used a Glyph icon on a button which's not working either. This is an unwanted distraction and an overall sub-optimal user experience.

Here's my code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Site Title</h1>
        <p>Some text describing the site functionality</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</br>
</br>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="container">
        <label for="url-entered">Name for label</label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url-entered" autofocus onFocus="this.select();" onkeyup="onEnterKeyUp(event, this)" placeholder="Some placeholder text here">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-custom" type="button" onClick="trimURL()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">Crop it!</span></button>
        </div><!--input-group ends here -->
        <div class="res" id="hidden-res" style="margin-top: 15px; visibility: hidden;">
          <span id="err-msg"></span><a id="trimmed-link"></a>
        </div>        
        </span>
        <p>Mail me at <a href="mailto:admin@site.com">admin@site.com</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you suggest a solution for these issues? Thank you.

Comment: Please post the relevant code (and no more code than that) directly in your question. An unknown external URL will not be visited by most people here for security reasons, and once the problem is fixed this question will be useless for posterity.

Comment: You need to add glyphicon fonts in your fonts folder

Comment: @jyoti Can you tell me where to get the same? I've read online where suggestions varied from extracting the fonts from the bootstrap zip file and placing the fonts folders in local fonts folder to download the glyphicon fonts themselves and placing them to linking them from remote location. So need a little clarity :)

Comment: @blazemonger Edited now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @HarshaKanchina You need to download the bootstrap.zip. Copy the fonts from `fonts folder` and place in your `local fonts folder`. Hope it works :)

Comment: @Jyoti Thanks Jyoti. It finally worked after a couple of other changes :)